# Data field not displaying data from JSON correctly in Swift 3

Tags: arrays, iphone, json, swift, swift3

I am developing an application for iPhone. I have successfully got the data coming into the app. The problem I have is that Some of the data structure from the JSON is a little different from the others, so it is not coming in or not letting my data display. My code so far is:

**UPDATED**

**JSON Structure that is causing the issue**

```
categories: [
   {
name: "Here and now"
   }
],
```

**Swift code in view Controller that**

```
guard let dic2 = post["categories"] as? [[String: Any]] else {
                    return
          }
                for category in dic2 {
                guard let content = category["name"] as? String else {
                return
               }
          }
```

Then the following code is to append the postinput

```
postsinput.append(postinput.init(mainImage: mainImage, name: title, author: author, summary: summary, content: content, categories: content))
```

Then the following is to put the output to a tag

```
let catLabel = cell?.viewWithTag(4) as! UILabel
catLabel.text = (postsinput[indexPath.row].categories).replacingOccurrences(of: "<[^>]+>", with: "", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)
```

So after all this it does not work, the output in the viewcontroller is empty, and I am sure it is to do with my code not reading the data structure from the JSON correctly.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please read the JSON (not the dictionary representation after the deserialization !). It's pretty easy: `{}` is a dictionary, `[]` is an array. All keys are required to be `String`. All values in double quotes are `String`, numeric values with decimal places are `Double` without are `Int`, `true` /  `false` (not in double quotes) is `Bool` and `null` is `NSNull`. That's the entire type set of JSON.

Comment: PS: If you want to get a *real*  solution post the *real* JSON (string - at least the *real* keys and the *real* value types) rather than not related pseudo code and post also how the data source is populated. For example the *real* JSON seems to contain HTML tags.

Answer (score 0):

Categories is an array of dictionaries, so you should parse it in that structure.

```
var categories = [String]()
guard let dic2 = post["categories"] as? [[String: Any]] else {
    return
}
for category in dic2 {
    guard let content = category["name"] as? String else {
        return
    }
    categories.append(content)
}
```

Comment: I am adding this in but in the postinput.append, if i put in categories: content. It brings the content in and not the category. Is it getting confused with two contents being passed into content and category?

Comment: Why do you want to store the same information under both content and category?
You also need to create an array in which you store the names of categories and use that array to init your postinput object.

See my updated answer.

Comment: I don't want to store category in content, but that is how you answered the question unless i got confussed

Comment: Even in your original code you basically stored the same information in both. Namely you stored the name of a single category under content and stored the raw JSON data containing all categories under categories. You should clarify what you actually want to store under content, since from the code you have shown in your answer it seems like it is a redundant property.

Comment: Yes that's my bad, Content should be only for content and category only for category. Apologies for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

Presuming your JSON comes in like

```
{
    "categories": [{
        "name": "Here and now"
    }]
}
```

`categories` is not a dictionary, it's actually an array of dictionary objects. so this line will fail:

```
guard let dic2 = post["categories"] as? [String: Any]
```

it should be

```
guard let dic2 = post["categories"] as? [[String: Any]]
```